Basement Window Cracks/Gaps Around Foundation - Can see through gap from inside
I have a basement window that has gaps around the foundation of my house (see pics below for details). I'm becoming more worried because I can now see outside light from the inside of my window. Furthermore, I've noticed a lot of small gnats in my basement. Water pools a bit in the area outside near this window when it rains but then goes away fairly fast. I have a french drain along the inside perimeter of my basement along with a sump pump.
How serious does this issue look? How can I attempt to fix it myself? And could there be possible water damage or something that's attracting gnats?





Clean it up as others have said, but I prefer polyurethane caulk. It provides a better protection than silicone, in my opinion. It dries very rubbery and allows for expansion and contraction and the best thing is, it is paintable. The Vulkem brand comes in multiple colors.

It does not look serious. Just clean up all the old caulk, and apply new silicon-based exterior caulk. It's part of typical house maintenance.
